# Show that $\sum\limits^\infty_{k=1}k^{-s}$ converges if and only if $s>1$ for positive $s$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that $\sum\limits^\infty_{k=1}k^{-s}$ converges if and only if $s>1$ for positive $s$.

Sorry, no thinking process so far. I have a blockage right now. Any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test): Your series converges iff the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k \left(2^k \right)^{-s}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{k(1-s)} $$ converges - but the latter is a simple geometric series.

Comment: Nice...but take into account that you can use this *only* if the series' sequence is monotone decreasing to zero, so at least it must be $\;s>0\;$ . Not that it is a problem, but still...+1

Comment: Awesome, thanks! We don't need no fancy integrals!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Observe that the integral $$\int_{1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^s}dx$$ converges for $s>1$. When $s<1$, it diverges.

Comment: is there any other way?